# What are the kernel and cflags for AMD Phenom II x6 (K10 / Thuban)?

Tags: optimization, central-processing-unit

In the 2.6.35 kernel I have a choice of:

1. Operon/Athlon64/Hammer/K8
2. Generic-x86-64

The first option seems best but I'd like confirmation. I have no idea whether there is a specific -mcpu / -march flag for this processor. Are there any other tricks to optimise software for this processor.

I run Gentoo if that makes any difference.

UPDATE: I have found answer 2 from AMD themselves: http://www.amddevcentral.com/CPU/GNU/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: can you use -march=native here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use CFLAGS="-march=amdfam10 -O2 -pipe" (amd64,gentoo-source 2.6.34-r6,gcc 4.4.3-r2). Everything is stable and safe.

Comment: Ever tried -03 ? It's listed in the AMD GCC Quick Reference as "Aggresive Optimisation" so I'm kinda tempted.

Comment: No(simple about -O3 and optimize gcc http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7269). I try clang, but i have many problem.